Python PIL renders broken Bengali Characters on railway.app
I am trying to make an image renderer using python and Pillow (9.4.0) in which I have to put Bengali characters in the image. I was using ImageFont to do that and was using layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM and it worked fine in my computer (Zorin OS 16) but when I tried to deploy it on Railway it throwed error like
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageFont' has no attribute 'LAYOUT_RAQM'

How can I fix this? I know that if I get this error that means libraqm is not installed on the server. But I have no access to install something on the server in Railway.
Are there any work-arrounds?
Actually whatever I tried was working in my pc but not working on railway.app

The docs at https://nixpacks.com/docs/guides/configuring-builds#install-additional-packages indicate that during build process packages can be installed using apt-get. So probably need to install teh following: libfreetype6-dev, libharfbuzz-dev, libfribidi-dev, and libraqm-dev.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. At least, sufficient code snippet as well as  an example of Bengali characters put  in the image, and how are those rendered…

@JosefZ Pillow uses RAQM for font rendering if available otherwise it falls back to Basic rendering. Basic rendering has no Opentype support, so only the simplest of text will work, not even all Latin script will render correctly. For correct rendering for Bengali and for that matter any Opentype support you need libraqm installed, which in term needs frretype, harfbuzz and fribidi. Similarly for matplotlib, seaborn, wordcloud etc whichh all rely on mplcairo which in turn needs libraqm, etc.

Use layout_engine=ImageFont.Layout.RAQM, as described here.
